# How do I call a specific function when a SIGTERM or SIGKILL system signal is received?

Tags: python, flask, webserver, uwsgi

I'm in need of a solution when I want to execute a particular function in my flask app before shutting the app completely (Essentially, a graceful shutdown).

I'm running a flask server with uwsgi (1 process, 4 threads) and I have tried the following to capture signals.

1. Use Python signal and register signal in main thread. Unable to propagate them to worker or sub threads.
2. Used the above solution with `"py-callos-afterfork": "True"` in uwsgi config file and still of no use
3. Tried preStop lifecycle hook in Kube but does not seem to do anything. Even the echo command is not printing. And I also assume the preStop hook runs as a separate process instead of the using the existing process

I have searched and there is no proper documentation for graceful shutdown with flask and uwsgi. There's a mention of master fifo with uwsgi but there are no examples of how to use them.

What could be a viable setup to perform graceful shutdown for my application? I'm open to other web frameworks (FastAPI?) or other web servers (maybe gunicorn) as well.

TLDR: Unable to capture SIGTERM and SIGKILL signals using above mentioned methods for my existing setup (flask framework with uwsgi web server). What could be a viable option for me to perform graceful shutdown? Reference articles or example are much appreciated. Thank you!